# React-native-image-picker add mask layout to camera

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-image-picker

I'm making an app, that implements taking photos or uploading them from gallery.
I would like to find out, if it is and how it is possible to add a mask layout for camera view.
The result i would like to get is :

[image: The orange border around the camera view.]

Is it possible to achieve this with react-native-image-picker ?
Docs doesn't provide any answer to this, would appreciate any answers that could help me find a solution, or choose a npm package, that suits my needs :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with expo-camera or react-native-camera but I don't know how to do it with react-native-image-picker